# Show CMD window for Powershell Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a power shell script that runs 3 batch files.
When running this with task scheduler, I want to be able to see the cmd windows with the batch files running. Is this possible.

Comment: Is the scheduled task running in your context?

Comment: Yes, the task is running the powershell. The powershell runs the batch files passing through parameters. When I just run the powershell the cmd winowns come up. I want that to happen when its running as a scheduled task. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: How is the task configured to run.

Comment: To run weather the user is logged in or not.  And it needs to be done this way.(Unless your asking for a different configuration)

Comment: That is your problem.  You will only see the console windows if the task is configured to run only when the user is logged in.

Comment: There's no work around?

Comment: This may be an X-Y problem. Why do you want it to show the boxes?

Comment: I want it to show the cmd windows to for when I get in I can see that my programs are running and what step they are at.

Comment: I would suggest having them write to a log file then.

Comment: I agree; the usual thing to do is perform logging in your script so you can examine later without needing a visual.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Windows has significant logging capabilities. Would your logging be suitable for application event logging? See `EVENTCREATE /?` for more information.

Comment: I have logging setup to check the progress. Showing the cmd windows thought would be very advantages though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize the answer from the post [Windows 7 Task Scheduler to start application in user session](https://superuser.com/questions/278233/windows-7-task-scheduler-to-start-application-in-user-session).

When a scheduled task is executed, it is run in session 0, which means that the windows won't display. To have Task Scheduler show when a task is running, run it in interactive mode. It appears this option can only be set from the schtasks utility and not from the task scheduler.

/IT: A value that enables the task to run interactively only if the /RU user is currently logged on at the time the task runs. The task runs only if the user is logged on.

```
schtasks /Create /IT ...
```